# TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have python class:

```
class Athlete:
    def __init__(self,fullName,dob,times):
        self.fullName = fullName
        self.dob = dob
        self.times = times
    ##  print('times is ',times)

    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join("Athlete[fullName="+self.fullName +",dob="+self.dob+",sortedTimes="+self.sortedTimes+"]")

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Instances of this class are stored in map `athleteMap` as values.

When I do `print(athleteMap)` I get this error:

```
File "D:/Software/ws/python_ws/collections\athleteList.py", line 11, in __str__
    return ''.join("Athlete[fullName="+self.fullName +",dob="+self.dob+",sortedTimes="+self.sortedTimes+"]")
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

I need to print `Athlete` instance in print method.

How to do this in python?

Comment: Try calling `str` on `self.sortedTimes` (or, better yet, use `str.format`)

Comment: with `self.sortedTimes` you mean `self.times`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `times` to a string explicitly then:

```
return "Athlete[fullName=" + self.fullName  + ",dob=" + self.dob + ",sortedTimes=" + str(self.sortedTimes) + ']'
```

You don't need `''.join()` here.

A better option is to use string formatting:

```
return "Athlete[fullName={0.fullName},dob={0.dob},sortedTimes={0.sortedTimes}]".format(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `join` call doesn't make sense. You probably want something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Athlete[fullName="
        + str(self.fullName)
        + ",dob="
        + str(self.dob)
        + ",sortedTimes="
        + str(self.sortedTimes)
        + "]"
```

I've added `str` to every attribute because I can't know for sure in which one of them you put a `list`. The problem is evident from the error - lists can't be converted implicitly to string - you need to mark this conversion explicitly via `str()` call. One of your attributes (`dob` or `times` most probably) is a list.